# Algolia Instant Search Firebase Cloud Function - how to get the other value?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, algolia

I don't have much idea about JavaScript, so I used [Algolia's Instant Search for Firebase Github Repository](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/fulltext-search) to build my own function.

My function:

```
exports.indexentry = functions.database.ref('/posts/{postid}/text').onWrite(event => {
  const index = client.initIndex(ALGOLIA_POSTS_INDEX_NAME);
  const firebaseObject = {
    text: event.data.val(),
   timestamp: event.data.val(),
    objectID: event.params.postid
  };
```

In Algolia indices, with timestamp as the key, I get the same value as in text field, but in Firebase backend timestamp is different. How to fix this?

I tried different statements to get timestamp value but couldn't.

**Edit**

*Expected Outcome*:

```
{
    text: "random rext",
    timestamp: "time stamp string",
    author: "author name",
    object ID: "object ID"
}
```

*Actual Outcome*

```
{
    text: "entered text",
    object ID: "object ID"
}
```

Comment: Answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44532715/cloud-functions-for-firebase-to-index-firebase-database-objects-in-algolia/44570296#44570296).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not real clear about your goal.  [Event](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.Event#timestamp) has a timestamp property.  Have you tried:

```
  const firebaseObject = {
    text: event.data.val(),
    timestamp: event.timestamp, // <= CHANGED
    objectID: event.params.postid
  };
```

If you want a `long` instead of `string`, use `Date.parse(event.timestamp)`

Comment: There may be other fields as well, for example, `author_name` that we may need to index, is there a generalized way to do that or do I write separate functions for every field?

Comment: Someone else will have to help you with that--I don't have experience with Algolia,

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT 2:** Answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44532715/cloud-functions-for-firebase-to-index-firebase-database-objects-in-algolia/44570296#44570296).

**Original Answer:** What Bob Snyder said about the timestamp event is correct.

> There may be other fields as well, for example, author_name that we may need to index, is there a generalized way to do that or do I write separate functions for every field?

If you want a general way to add all fields, I think what you are looking for can be found [here](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/integrations/firebase-algolia/#ongoing-live-sync-to-algolia). This should give you the right guidance to get what you want, i.e save your whole object into the Algolia index.

**EDIT:**

```
index.saveObject(firebaseObject, function(err, content) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    console.log('Firebase object indexed in Algolia', firebaseObject.objectID);
  });
```

Comment: I'm sure there's a way modifying this as well, I'm unable to run the other one because of some reasons, when I try to run it, the existing functions stop running. 

I made random hit and trial changes in my code and I started getting full objects but I removed it because of another bug, and now I'm unable to do it again.

Comment: And `addOrUpdateIndexRecord()` is running, finished with status `ok`, still I am not getting full JSON in Algolia, while the github one is working.

Comment: @BugsBuggy Thanks for the reply. It's hard for me to know what is the exact reason of the problem because I don't have enough information. If possible, can you edit your question and add more details, such as "code - expected outcome - actual outcome"?

Comment: The document code does not give any outcome whatsoever. It does run though, as I can see in logs.

The github code runs, I am mentioning the expected and actual outcomes in the question.

Comment: I added the expected and actual outcomes

Comment: @BugsBuggy So to make sure: 1- You are doing `index.saveObject`, is that correct (like I show in my Edit of the answer)? 2- the console.log is giving success? 3- does your firebaseObject that you use in your code contain `text`, `timestamp` and `author`, or just `text`? 4- Are you sure there was a `onWrite` event in Firebase so that the function is called and is the entry is updated in Algolia?

Comment: So I checked everything, my function is just not getting deployed. The other function in the file are getting deployed but not mine (built in reference to the documentation). Something I noticed, other functions start with `exports.<name>= ... ` and this one starts as `function updateIndex ( dataSnapshot) `... I do not understand why it is not getting deployed.

Comment: Please see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44522009/unable-to-deploy-firebase-function

Comment: @BugsBuggy hmm I am no expert of Node js. I just want to make sure that you added `contactsRef.on('child_added', addOrUpdateIndexRecord);
contactsRef.on('child_changed', addOrUpdateIndexRecord);` as is mentioned in the tutorial link I posted in my answer?

Comment: Yes that I did, but regardless at least the console should add the function, isn't it?

Comment: @BugsBuggy I guess so... never tried node.js so I am not sure there :(

Answer (score 0):

`event.data.val()` returns the entire firebase snapshot. If you want a specific value in your data you add it after `.val()` for example if every post has an author stored in your firebase database under they key "author" you can get this value using `var postAuthor = event.data.val().author`

I've included some samples from my code for those interested. A sample post looks like this: 
[image]

Then inside my cloud functions I can access data like this:

```
const postToCopy = event.data.val(); // entire post
const table = event.data.val().group;
const category = event.data.val().category;
const region = event.data.val().region;
const postKey = event.data.val().postID;
```