# Unable to deploy firebase function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, algolia

Node.js command prompt is simply ignoring this function, while the other functions are getting deployed, I am not getting any error either.

```
var database = admin.database();
var postsRef = database.ref("/posts");

postsRef.on('child_added', addOrUpdateIndexRecord);

function addOrUpdateIndexRecord(dataSnapshot) {
  // Get Firebase object
  var firebaseObject = dataSnapshot.val();
  // Specify Algolia's objectID using the Firebase object key
  firebaseObject.objectID = dataSnapshot.key;
  // Add or update object
  index.saveObject(firebaseObject, function(err, content) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    console.log('Firebase object indexed in Algolia', firebaseObject.objectID);
  });
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to deploy this snippet as a Cloud Function for Firebase using `firebase deploy`? If so, you're using the wrong syntax. The snippet defines a function that is triggered by database changes when using the regular Firebase SDK. To trigger a Cloud Function, use the syntax shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a database trigger function, then the syntax you are using is not correct. Try doing this way:

```
exports.updateposts = functions.database.ref("posts/")
.onWrite(event => {

  //Do whatever you want to do with trigger

});
```