# Cloud Functions for Firebase to index Firebase Database Objects in Algolia

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, algolia

I went through docs, github repositories but nothing worked for me yet.

**My datastructure:**

```
App {
    posts : {
        <post_keys> : {
            auth_name : "name",
            text : "some text" //and many other fields
                      }
            }
    }
```

1) [Github repository](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/fulltext-search) : If I use this, I only get one field from one function, if I need all the fields, I would need to write separate functions for each, which is a bad approach.

2) [Algolia Official Docs for Node.js](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/integrations/firebase-algolia/#ongoing-live-sync-to-algolia) : This cannot be deployed as a cloud function, but it does what I intend to do.

How can I write a function that can be deployed on Firebase and gets the whole object indexed with its key in Algolia?

Comment: Can you show what you tried? Also check out https://discourse.algolia.com/t/firebase-guide-firebase-cloud-functions-examples/777

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I went ahead to create a Firebase Cloud function in order to index all objects in the Algolia index. This is the solution:

What you were doing is something like this:

```
exports.indexentry = functions.database.ref('/blog-posts/{blogid}/text').onWrite(event => {
```

What you should do is the following:

```
exports.indexentry = functions.database.ref('/blog-posts/{blogid}').onWrite(event => {
  const index = client.initIndex(ALGOLIA_POSTS_INDEX_NAME);
  var firebaseObject = event.data.val();
  firebaseObject.objectID = event.params.blogid;

  return index.saveObject(firebaseObject).then(
      () => event.data.adminRef.parent.child('last_index_timestamp').set(
          Date.parse(event.timestamp)));
});
```

The difference is in the first line: In the first case, you only listen to `text` changes, hence you only get the data containing the text change. 
In the second case, you get the whole object since you listen to changes in all of the blog object (notice how `/text` was removed).

I tested it and it works for me: whole object including author was indexed in Algolia.